# Ideas for charting data

Tags: algorithm, graph, charts, google-visualization

I have a set of values (temperature readings) that are like this : 0,1,3,3.3,3.44,10,11,11,11.1,11.4,11.4,11.5,12.1,13.1,14,15,19,50,67,70,81.

What I need is a type of horizontal line graph that looks like in the attached image but it can automatically split those values into 3 intelligent intervals ( for our example we see the most numbers are between 10 and 15 so that would be the main interval, and the other 2 will be for numbers smaller than 10 and for numbers bigger than 15).

So the plotted data would be something like : 
10% for between 1-10
70% for between 10-15
20% for 15+

Anyone have any ideas?!

Thank you

[click to see an example of the needed graph type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoTsm.jpg)

Comment: How many values are you expecting and what kind of performance are you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply M C :) Well .. i can get from 1 value to maximum 1000 values. The performance doesn't matter that much (if we can generate it in under 1 second on a 4-cores CPU).

Comment: In that case, you've probably got room for a O(N^2) or O(N^3) algorithm. Not familiar enough with Google Charts thought to help there, but seems like if you sort the points, divide them into three equal sets using 2 index locations as dividers, then move the dividers as required to get the desired effect, you should be able to group them. The issue though it's that I'm not clear what you mean by "intelligently". There are probably a good dozen or so ways to divide up the data into 3 parts that could likely be considered "intelligent". Hence why I'm leaving this as a long comment.

Comment: Thank you! I don't need google charts, if I found something suitable I can use other tools or build the graph from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is basically a **1-dimension clustering problem** (here's a similar question on [stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13781/clustering-1d-data)).

There are many algorithms to do this, for example [k-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means) or [Expectation-Maximisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_maximization). I'd suggest the former if you're looking for something simple.

Once you have your clustering, all you have left to do is to plug the data into whatever chart API you want to use.